# How to use the fdaTool to filter a sine wave from a wav file

Tags: matlab, filter, simulink, dac

Im having trouble finding the correct filter and values to use to filter the sine wave. So far I have got both the wav file and the sine wave combining but I just cant filter the sine wave.

If anyone can help i will be eternally grateful.

Below are the images of my setup which consist of the fdatool and the design of the process.

[image]

[image]

Large pictures here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQQNZ.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZc09.png

I have heard about a DAC with a matrix concatenate function to allow output but I have no idea what this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you want is a notch filter to remove just the content of your combined signal at the frequency of the injected sine wave.  This will have the effect of also removing any content at that frequency from the original signal, but probably will not be noticeable. I tried to attach an image but can't, but try setting the values in your fdatool to the following:

```
Bandstop
IIR: Butterworth
order 10
Fs = 43008
Fc1=1400
Fc2=1600
```

You can play around with the Fc1 and Fc2 values to widen/narrow the width of the notch. Hope this helps.

Comment: would it be possible to upload the image to imgur.com and share the image link please.

Comment: Give this a try: http://imgur.com/dHyGUSd   It is similar to your fdatool image, with the above values filled in.  You can see the filter shape now removes the frequency content around the specified frequencies in Fc1 through Fc2

Comment: Is there any way you could put on your design please? Then I can compare it to mine. Thank you by the way

Comment: I do not have a design put together, and unfortunately cannot put one together quickly because I do not have the DSP blockset needed to place the fdatool within a simulink model.  However, if the frequency of your sine wave falls within the notch that you've created, it should be removed.  You can play around with the width of the notch to see if it helps at all (ie, adjusting Fc1 and Fc2 to widen or narrow the notch).  How are you determining whether or not is has worked?  Are you listening to the combined sound before and after the filter and you can still make out the injected tone?

Comment: The part which i don't understand is the notch. I have put the settings from the image which you just sent me and my design up the top of the page is still the same. I looked in the library and all i could find was a peak notch filter. Do i have to incorporate this into the design and if so would i place it before or after the fdatool filter.

Comment: could it be something to do with the sample time? Because when you combine both the wav and sine wave they must be the same which i put as 1/42, but to listen just to a sine wave through an audio device i have to have the sampling rate at 1/44100 otherwise the connection is wrong

Comment: I would set the sample time to the sample step size of your audio file (1/43008), or the (1/44100) you've tried before.  The fdatool should design the notch filter if you use the specified parameters about.  If it is not, you could also try using just the coefficients for the filter in a discrete filter block.  Using the fdatool in matlab, the designed notch filter provides the following coefficients:

Comment: b = [0.953821340726740 -9.31109819670987 41.1266700866117 -108.228093485773 187.904405321432 -224.891409898954 187.904405321432 -108.228093485773 41.1266700866117 -9.31109819670987 0.953821340726740
], a = [1 -9.66958789209424 42.3066566050458 -110.282722312108 189.666703976628 -224.863055232540 186.113460572977 -106.189330271148 39.9731971928658 -8.96509755603107 0.909775150025762
].  That should provide the same frequency response as the filter from the fdatool I showed earlier.